# <xsi:nil="true"/> is coming how to remove this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, json, wcf

this kind of data is coming on retrive of data from wcf web service for values it is returnig proper values but for nil values it resurning this how to stop this it should return only data with xml not property like xm:nil

```
<FirstName xsi:nil="true"/><LastName xsi:nil="true"/>
```

my ddata is

```
<Contact>
  <Id>06</Id>
  <Key>11</Key>
  <First_Name xsi:nil="true"/>
</Contact>
```

i want to stop this xsi:nil="true" so it bringing [object,Object] on UI which is difficult to handle.please tell me any changes needed webcopnfig or anywhere which help to resove this?

Comment: we need set XMLNIL attr to ABSENT while XML CREATION From Dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need set XMLNIL attr to ABSENT while XML CREATION From Dataset
so we have make changes in query ---elements xsinil ABSENT